# Add custom location in weather applet

Tags: 11.04, applet

I am trying to add a custom location to the Weather Report applet (also known as libgweather) in Ubuntu 11.04. I am using libgweather 2.30.3-1ubuntu1.1, the latest available version for Ubuntu 11.04.

To add this location, I edited `/usr/share/libgweather/Locations.xml` and added the details from the weather station that I wanted as found on http://weather.noaa.gov/data/nsd_cccc.txt (a link that I found in some posting on another forum about an old version of libgweather).

The details entered do not provide weather data. The location does show up in the location list, however, the applet does not display any information.

Now my question is: where can I see where libgweather pulls the information from? I have read something about that Google is a source, but I would like to see which file on my system points to an information source so that I can maybe add a different source for that information.

Answer (score 2):

Found it (partially).

On http://live.gnome.org/LibGWeather/ForecastsAndRadar is says that http://weather.noaa.gov/ is the primary source of data.

I visited that site to see what weather data was available for my country. The city that I wanted to add was 'De Bilt', where the Royal Netherlands Meteorological Institute is situated and which happens to be the closest weather station to me. That station is not listed on http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/NL_cc.html, where all the weather stations available on the NOAA website for the Netherlands are listed.

Now figuring out a way how to add De Bilt anyway. So if anyone still has an answer to that, I would be very glad with that!